# try-with-resource is not supported in -source 1.5 error occured when I used try catch in the source

Tags: java, heroku, salesforce, try-catch

This is my pom.xml file.
[image]

And here is the error message:
[image]
I want to deploy my java project to heroku. But error occured.

```
try(Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {

    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    logger.info("Just Beforce sql executed ");
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select sfid,id, email from salesforce.contact");
    logger.info("ResultSet data " + rs);
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
      while (rs.next()) {
        logger.info("ID get Successfully " + rs.getString("id"));
         logger.info("SFID get Successfully " + rs.getString("sfid"));
         logger.info("Email get Successfully " + rs.getString("email"));
       }
 }
 catch (Exception e) {

 }
```

Apparently, the error is about try(Connection ...), but I just don't understand why it is not allowed.
And "is not supported in-source 1.5" confuses me, does it mean java version? or something else?
Any help will be appreciated!!!

**Update:I used git to deploy my app, here is my git project link:https://github.com/BenHugh/devcenter-java-quartz**

Comment: It seems that the compiler and the project JRE compliance version differ. Either check you build settings to compile in higher version or change the compliance settings in you IDE to get those error before compilation (Eclipse: Project > Properties > Java Compiler > JDK Compliance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax was implemented in Java 1.7. Heroku thinks that you are writing java 1.5 code. Can you change the project settings so that it understands that you are using (at least) Java 1.7?

Comment: java 7 actually

Comment: Thanks, you guys!  I'm pretty new about this. Can you tell me what settings should I change. Heroku settings or Java project settings?

Comment: Depends on how you project is set up. Do you have a pom.xml or build.gradle file? Hiw do you build it on your computer?

Comment: @JohanTidén Oh, I have a pom.xml file indeed, the java version is 1.6 now, I'll change it to 7 and see what happens

Comment: @Ben it depends on the requirement of you target runtime. If it runs on java 1.5, change the java project settings, if it runs on java 1.7 or higher change it on  the build

Comment: @JohanTidén I changed the java version from 1.6 to 7 in my pom.xml file, but it still show the same error. I don't have a build.gradle file.

Comment: @jhamon Thank you for your replying, I added my pom.xml file up there, please check it out. I used git to deploy my app. So I can't change the settings through IDE

Comment: Java version needs to be 1.7. I'll update my answer. It's just usually referred to as just 7.

Comment: Yep, java version is always "1.X" until java 11 where it's now just "X"

Comment: @JohanTidén I updated my question, added my pom.xml and error message image. I changed the version to 1.7, it still shows the error

Comment: I think it needs to be java.compiler.source. https://www.baeldung.com/manev-java-version

Comment: @jhamon My java version was 1.6, not 1.5, and changed it to higher version, but still can not deploy

Comment: @JohanTidén I'm afraid the link is invalid

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your properties `<java.version>` makes only sense if you are using Spring Boot

Change your properties to something like:

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

Or via the Maven Java compiler plugin configuration

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.1</version>
      <configuration>
         <source>1.8</source>
         <target>1.8</target>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Or alternatively use the classic try-catch syntax and close your connection manuall

```
try{
   Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
   // rest of your code
   connection.close();
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
   }
```